# If/Then Statement Evaluation

Tags: conditional

Really rudimentary question here...why is the following if/then statement always evaluating both "True" and "False" expressions and updating my CurCost and Temp variable values?

```
if[(1 === 2), (CurCost = CurCost + 165), (Temp = 99)]
```

Does not matter how I've bracketed it or rearranged it...Any quick response or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `If`not "if". Also mind the difference between `==` and `===`.

Comment: Got it - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that the built-in function `If` is written with a capital "I".

Comment: Graumagier - thanks for this assist...your answer solved a lot of frustration.